# Using AssetSync to deploy to an S3 bucket subdirectory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, asset-pipeline

I'm using AssetSync to sync to an S3 bucket. It seems to work fine. However, I'd like to be able to add versioning to the S3 bucket. So instead of just the bucket name, I want to put the deployed assets into a subdirectory like

my-bucket/v1/

I tried adding the 'v1' folder to the FOG_DIRECTORY env var, but that doesn't seem to be the thing to do. Is there an easy way to specify a subdir of a bucket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer myself. Thanks for nothin'.

AssetSync.config.assets.prefix